# Oracle view to return single column from multiple select columns

Tags: oracle

query 1: I need to get the dept code from one table. 
query 2: use that dept code to query another table which also has got another set of dept code. kind of one is to many, one dept referring to many depts.

NOTE: they don't have the same column name in two tables.

and the final result should be union of 1st query and 2nd query.

for eg: query 1 result : ECE
        query 2 result : EEE, Mech, Comp. Sc.

I need the result to be ECE, EEE, Mech, Comp. Sc.

```
declare default_dept_Code varchar2(10);
begin
select dept_code into default_dept_Code from (select dept_code from 
course_per WHERE student_no ='526765771');

dbms_output.put_line(default_dept_Code);

SELECT dept_code FROM course_per WHERE student_no ='526765771'
union all
select add_dept_code from addition_dept where dept_Code = default_dept_Code;
```

I'm unable to execute this query, it has got error. What are the other best ways I can handle it, I need to put this in a VIEW. I tried to create temp table and insert the select result into it, did not work. I'm a new bee to Oracle. I don't want to use cursor, if that is the only option I can go for it.

Comment: Please post table structure (table and column names, data types of the columns, and primary key and foreign key designations) and sample data, with the desired result from the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you can write your query like this:

```
SELECT dept_code as code 
    FROM course_per 
    WHERE student_no ='526765771'
UNION ALL
SELECT add_dept_code as code 
    FROM addition_dept 
    WHERE dept_Code = (
        SELECT dept_code
        FROM course_per 
        WHERE student_no ='526765771');
```

Comment: but, in a view i don't want to use the where clause, in .net c# table adapter I can handle this where clause, my problem here is I have only 5 rows in my addition_dept table, but the course_per table is huge, any idea?